# Google Analytics - add third party shopping cart to main domain reports

Tags: google-analytics

We would like to track if users sent from our main site to a third party site have bounced or clicked on "Register"
They are willing to put our Analytics code in their pages - both product and registration. 
I looked at what is suggested by Google but not clear about a few things.

Our current code on our site:

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-nnnnn-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Code suggested by Google to be on the third party site:

```javascript
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'my-example-blogsite.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
...
<a href="http://dogs.example-petstore.com/intro.html"
   onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', 'http://dogs.example-petstore.com/intro.html']); return false;">
   See my pet store</a>
```

Our code has 'none' in this line: _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);

Google's sample code has the URL

```javascript
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'my-example-blogsite.com']);
```

Does it matter? Do I need to enter the domain as suggested?

Also Google's code has a link back to our site as follows

```javascript
onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', 'http://dogs.example-petstore.com/intro.html']); return false;"
```

Do we need to have a link back? Can we remove the `onclick` code or will it affect the reporting?
Thanks!
Myalo

Answer (score 0):

You need the onclick event. What is does is to "decorate" the link, i.e. it adds the url parameters that need to be carried over to the other domain (where they are picked up by the Google code and used to continue the session).

Please be aware that the code you are using is horribly outdated. If at all possible switch to the current version (Universal Analytics). While cross domain tracking on Universal Analytics works by the same principle it'S somewhat more elegant (uses a single parameter as opposed to the unwieldy query string for classic GA) and offers a number of helper functions to make cross domain tracking easier.